# OCaml beginner needs help: What is wrong?

Tags: ocaml

Code:

```
let rec get_val (x, n) = match x with
    [] -> -1
  | if (n=0) then (h::_) -> h 
    else (_::t) -> get_val(t, n-1)
;;
```

Error message:

```
Characters 55-57:
| if (n=0) then (h::_) -> h 
  ^^
Error: Syntax error
```

Comment: Ouch!  Please review http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help and clearly state what your question is.

Comment: Just an FYI, by putting parentheses around the function arguments (x, n) you are defining the function get_val to take a SINGLE variable that is a tuple containing a list and an integer.  Not really wrong, but probably unintentional.

let rec get_val x n = ...

is probably what you meant.

Answer (score 8):

I think the problem is that you are trying to put an `if` expression into a pattern-matching statement.  The left-hand side of each `->` needs to correspond to a valid pattern for `x`.

Try this:

```
let rec get_val (x, n) = match x with

    [] -> -1

  | h::t -> if (n=0) then h 
                     else get_val(t, n-1)

;;
```

Answer (score 8):

You can't mix if and match like that, you must either use the if after the pattern, as already proposed, or use guarded patter as in:

```
let rec get_val x n = 
  match x with
    [] -> -1
  | h::_ when n=0 -> h 
  | _::t ->  get_val t (n-1)
;;
```

note also that ocaml is curried, and you don't usually put parenthesis around function's arguments